# how to prove that statement b implies statement a in Casella and Berger Theorem 1.5.10?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

In Casella and Berger's textbook *Statistical Inference (2nd Edition)*, page 34, Theorem 1.5.10 says that the following two statements are equivalent:

a. The random variables X and Y are identically distributed.

b.$F_X(x)=F_Y(x)$ for every x.

The authors give the following definition of random variables being identically distributed :

> **Definition 1.5.8 :** The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are *identically distributed* if for every measurable set $A$, $P(X\in A) = P(Y\in A)$

The proof that statement b implies statement a is omitted in the book. I'm wondering how shall we proceed in proving it. A sketch of the proof, or complete proof or lecture notes/textbook reference are welcome.

Comment: In many texts, the definition of $X$ and $Y$ being identically distributed is taken to be that $F_X=F_Y$, so it would be helpful to include your/the textbook's definition of identically distributed random variables

Comment: See Proposition $2.2.3$ and Corollary $2.2.2$ of Sidney Resnick's _A Probability Path_. It's a nice application of Dynkin's theorem.

Comment: @Priestley Thanks. The definition for identically distributed has been added as Definition 1.5.8

Comment: @User1865345 Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\mathcal{H}:=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a generator of the Borel sets $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and it is stable under finite intersections. We get, by assumption (first inclusion) and construction (second inclusion)
$$\mathcal{H}\subseteq \mathcal{C}:=\{B\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}):P(X\in B)=P(Y\in B)\}\subseteq \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
We prove $\mathcal{C}$ is a Dynkin system: (1) $P(X \in \mathbb{R})=1=P(Y\in \mathbb{R})$; (2) $C \in \mathcal{C}$ implies $P(X \in C^c)=1-P(X \in C)=1-P(Y\in C)=P(Y\in C^c)$ so $C^c \in \mathcal{C}$; (3) if $(C_n)\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ are disjoint, then $P(X \in \cup_nC_n)=\sum_nP(X \in C_n)=\sum_nP(Y \in C_n)=P(Y \in \cup_nC_n)$ so $\cup_nC_n \in \mathcal{C}$. By $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathcal{C}$. We conclude $\mathcal{C}=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question, after we arrived at $\mathcal{C}=\mathscr{B}(R)$, why does this mean statement b implies statement a? To me it seems that we need $\mathcal{H}=\mathscr{B}(R)$ or $\mathscr{B}(R)\subset\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @ExcitedSnail  Statement (b) is our premise and it is used in $\mathcal{H}\subseteq \mathcal{C}$. We know that $\sigma(\mathcal{H})=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ because $\mathcal{H}$ is a generator of Borel sets. To show that $\mathcal{C}=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ means that all sets $B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ are s.t. $P(X \in B)=P(Y\in B)$, thus showing (a).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful.